# A data migration issue in HSQL, the new database does not contain few tables

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, hsqldb

I am currently responsible for migrating data for our application, for upgrading to new version.I am trying to migrate from HSQL to HSQL, later we will move on to other combinations.

So I have a stand alone utility to do this. I am using MockServletContext to initialize my services(this migration is to be done without starting the servers).

The problem is that all the tables are migrated except for 2-3 tables, the number depending on size of the data migrated. On extensive debugging I found nothing wrong. Meaning that all the data is getting migrated on debugging via eclipse, but on normal running it fails to complete for the last 3 tables.

Any clue where to look at?

In normal run I have put loggers to see if we are reading all the data from the source database and indeed the logs prove we do.
The only place where I am unable to put logs is when it calls a method in driver.

In the last step we give a call to PreparedStatement object's executeBatch()/executeUpdate() methods(Tried with both but exactly same result).

I am completeley clueless what to do and where to look for. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> In normal run I have put loggers to see if we are reading all the data from the source database and indeed the logs prove we do. The only place where I am unable to put logs is when it calls a method in driver.

If you suspect something wrong there, try wrapping your driver in [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/). It will show the SQL issued to DB. Good luck!

Comment: But I am getting correct result on running in debug mode whereas not in normal run mode. Does it ring some kind of a bell? I mean I want to get this problem solved but I also want to know why this behavior is happening.

Comment: @user391972 That's why I recommended it. Add SQL logging in NORMAL run mode, see what happens exactly. The answer is generic, and so is your problem description. If you reveal more, firstly and mostly the SQL statement that fails to process your data, maybe you could be helped better.

Comment: I inspected the SQL queries and to no surprise they are as expected. Inserting proper rows to corresponding tables.  So am still stuck at this :(